# Multi-dimensional array pascal syntac error

Tags: pascal, multidimensional-array

i did this and its working slightly better, now i get the error: 
45 / 44 matric.pas
 Fatal: Syntax error, ) expected but const char found
It is probable because i am using pascal graph.

```
program MatrixArray;
Uses wincrt,graph;
Var
GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode: Smallint;
Xaxis: array[1..10] of string;
Yaxis: array[1..10] of string;
Matrix: array[1..10,1..10] of string;
x:integer;
y:integer;
{two var's are needed for initialisation}
Begin
Writeln('Loading Game Graphics...');
GraphicsDriver := Detect;
InitGraph(GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode,'');
ClearViewPort;
```

declaring the arrays

```
Xaxis[1] :='A';
Xaxis[1] :='B';
Xaxis[1] :='C';
Xaxis[1] :='D';
Xaxis[1] :='E';
Xaxis[1] :='F';
Xaxis[1] :='G';
Xaxis[1] :='H';
Xaxis[1] :='I';
Xaxis[1] :='J';

Yaxis[1] :='1';
Yaxis[1] :='2';
Yaxis[1] :='3';
Yaxis[1] :='4';
Yaxis[1] :='6';
Yaxis[1] :='7';
Yaxis[1] :='8';
Yaxis[1] :='9';
Yaxis[1] :='10';

for x := 1 to 10 do
 for y := 1 to 10 do
     Matrix[x,y] := Xaxis[x] + Yaxis[y];

     For x := 1 to 10 do
         for y := 1 to 10 do
```

outtextxy is like writeln(); http://pascal-programming.info/lesson8.php

```
             OutTextXY(0,0, Matrix[x,y]' ');

End.
```

Comment: replaced OutTextYX(0,0, Matrix[x,y]' ');

Comment: with  OutText(Matrix[x,y]); it worked

Comment: You probably mean `Xaxis[2] :='B';`, `Xaxis[3] :='C';`, etc. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OutTextXY` routine probably expects two integers and one string as input. The Matrix array holds strings, so use:

```
OutTextXY(0, 0, Matrix[x, y]);
```

(Note the missing `' '`.)